# 'there will be' gerund or infinitive

Tags: word-usage, gerund-vs-infinitive

Which one is better:

> There will be a lot of voters **to vote** in the election.

or

> There will be a lot of voters **voting** in the election.

Comment: There's no real difference in meaning, though the second one is far more natural.

Answer (score -1):

Only the second sentence completes the verb phrase. The first sentence does not, and the first sentence also has an incomplete prepositional phrase because of the infinitive. Because of this, only the second sentence is correct, making it the better sentence by default.

Consider the erroneous rearrangement of the first sentence:

> A lot of voters will be to vote in the election.

Consider the rearrangement of the second sentence:

> A lot of voters will be voting in the election.

The rearrangement of the first sentence still fails to communicate that many votes will be cast, while the rearrangement of the second sentence continues to communicate that many votes will be cast.

To complete the first sentence, the incomplete verb phrase and incomplete prepositional phrase can be completed:

> There will be a lot of voters showing up to vote in the election.

And rearranged:

> A lot of voters will be showing up to vote in the election.

The addition of a gerund ("showing") completes the verb phrase ("will be showing") and the addition of a preposition ("up") that isn't part of the infinitive completes the prepositional phrase ("up to vote in the election"). The verb phrase tells what's happening. The prepositional phrase tells where it's happening. Now the completed first sentence communicates that the election will have many voters participating in it by voting.